# Remove all client-side stored data on website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

Client-side data can be stored in many different ways (cookies, localStorage, granted permissions, etc.). On my website I want to have a "Clear data" button, and when the user clicks on that one I want to remove all client-side stored data, so there's no trace of the user ever have visited my website on the client's computer. Do web browser contains an API for that? (and if so, how do I use it?) Or do I have to use each individual storage-related API and tell each to delete the data it has stored?

Answer (score 3):

you can call an API and add `Clear-Site-Data:"*"` in the header of that `HTTP` response. you can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data)

if you want to handle it with `javascript` code, this might help you

```
sessionStorage.clear()

localStorage.clear()

caches.keys().then(keys => {
  keys.forEach(key => caches.delete(key))
})

indexedDB.databases().then(dbs => {
  dbs.forEach(db => indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name))
})

document.cookie = document.cookie.split(';').reduce((newCookie1, keyVal) => {
  var pair = keyVal.trim().split('=')
  if (pair[0]) {
    if (pair[0] !== 'path' && pair[0] !== 'expires') {
      newCookie1 += pair[0] + '=;'
    }
  }
  return newCookie1
}, 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path:/;')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's for an SPA, so I can't use HTTP headers. That JS-solution seems also a bit risky since I might forget to remove some data. For one, your code does not remove traces of granted permissions.